# Why aspose word Run parentNode can be StructuredDoccumentTag

Tags: java, aspose.words

for the aspose word API,

https://apireference.aspose.com/java/words/com.aspose.words/run#ParentNode

> Run can only be a child of Paragraph.

but  I find the parent node of Run is StructredDocumentTag, why?

```
System.out.println("x.getClass().getName()=" + x.getClass().getName()); //return com.aspose.words.Run
System.out.println("x.getParentNode().getClass().getName()="+ x.getParentNode().getClass().getName()); //return com.aspose.words.StructuredDocumentTag!!
```

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Run can also be a child of SDT. The documentation must be updated. SDT actually can appear in almost any place of the document
https://apireference.aspose.com/java/words/com.aspose.words/StructuredDocumentTag
If it is placed in inline level it can contain any content that paragraph can.